# how can i modify the default wordpress sidebar

Tags: theme-development, widgets, sidebar

I need to hide the **Uncategorized** category from the default sidebar.

I edited the file `wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-categories.php`, but I did not see any changes. Here is an image of my sidebar, where the **blog** is listed under the "**Uncategorized**" category, which I want to hide.

[image]

how can i achieve this?

Comment: That's not the default WordPress sidebar. It's a widget or block added by a theme or plugin.

Comment: How I can found this code

Answer (score 0):

Editing the core WordPress files (like `class-wp-widget-categories.php`) directly is a no-go. When WordPress updates, it'll overwrite any changes you made to the core files. Plus, it's generally frowned upon in the developer community—it's just not a good habit to get into.

If the widget you're using is the core's default category widget, try adding the following code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
function exclude_categories($args){
    $exclude = get_cat_ID('Blog'); // Get the ID of the category you want to exclude
    $args["exclude"] = $exclude; // Exclude the category
    return $args;
}
add_filter("widget_categories_args","exclude_categories");
```

After adding this, the "Blog" category should disappear from the sidebar. If it's still playing coy, clear your cache, then take another look.

Comment: It is not hiding even I cleared my Cache

Comment: Looks like the widget you're trying to edit isn't core's category widget.

Comment: I don't know but I found this sidebar In apparence section of WordPress and here they said default sidebar.

Comment: What theme are you using? Can you try switching to a different theme like core's defaults themes and see if that widget exists after you change theme? If it's not there, that means it's a widget added by a theme/plugin.